# Coroutine - Reuse?

Tags: c++, caching, boost, coroutine

I'm currently allocating new coroutine instances quite often (see the code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106475/convert-algorithm-to-use-coroutines)).

The overhead of this is not trivial.

I would guess that there is some way to make this cheaper by reusing the previously allocated coroutine?

Not sure how to achieve this though?

I could use a boost::pool for the coroutine `Allocator`. However, that will not work for the `StackAllocator`, which is the expensive one...

Answer (score 3):

A coroutine contains a stack and a control block (preserved registers, put at the edge of the stack).
You could not reuse the coroutine itself but you could write your own stack-allocator which pre-allocates and caches stacks.
A newly created coroutine could re-use an already allocated stack from the cache.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid writing writing own stack allocator? I.e. if there already exists such allocator, it's better to use it rather than reinventing the own one?